# jquery click link and get radio input value to change text in span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click the link, to get the radio input value then replace the text in the span with that value.
http://jsfiddle.net/NY26v/

```
<INPUT class=width name=classname value=newclass1 CHECKED type=radio />
<INPUT class=width name=classname value=newclass2 type=radio />
<INPUT class=width name=classname value=newclass3 type=radio />

<P>
<A id=generate class=mainlink href="javascript:void(0)">the generate link </A>
</P>

<P>
&lt;P&gt;<BR>
&lt;A <b>class=someclass<SPAN id=classnumber>newclass1</SPAN></b> href="yourlink.html"&gt;your link&lt;/A&gt;<BR>
&lt;/P&gt;
</P>
```

------Jquery----

```
$(document).ready(function(){

// when the link #generate is clicked
$('#generate').click(function() {
// get the checked value in the radio input group .classname
var cn = $("input[name='classname']:checked").val();
//  in the #classnumber span
var classnumbertext = $('#classnumber').text();
// put the .classname radio value
$('#classnumber').text("newclass'+ (cn)");
});

});
```

Comment: you have mismatched single/double quotes on your last line of jquery.  Assuming you mean "newclass (" + cn +")" ?  You're also never using classnumbertext, get rid of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you are setting the text of the span to the following *string literal* value:

```
"newclass'+ (cn)"
```

That is, the actual letters `"c"` and `"n"` are part of the string, as is the single quote and the plus sign. To use the *variable* `cn` you need to put it and the `+` outside the double-quoted string, so perhaps you want this:

```
$('#classnumber').text("newclass" + cn);
// OR
$('#classnumber').text("newclass (" + cn + ")");
// OR
$('#classnumber').text(cn);
```

Demo of each: http://jsfiddle.net/NY26v/2/, http://jsfiddle.net/NY26v/4/, http://jsfiddle.net/NY26v/3/